# Mac App Store Download does not start on fresh installed Lion

Tags: macos, mac-appstore

I needed to reinstall Mac OS X, so my plan was to format the drive, install OS X Lion (since I have the USB stick here) and then update to Mavericks.
Sounds simple, yet I have a problem: The Mavericks download does not start! I logged into the App Store and clicked on Load, and it says that the download is in progress.

But: Nothing happens. I do not get a progress bar in the Purchased Menu and the Icon in Launchpad only says it is Loading but the progress bar there does not change.
**I tried another already purchased app and it did not work either!**

I deleted everything in the App Store download folder - no success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try resetting the Mac App Store.

1. Enable the debug menu and restart the Mac App Store.

   ```
   defaults write com.apple.appstore ShowDebugMenu -bool true
   ```
2. Choose the **Reset Application** option.

   [image: App Store Debug Menu]